# Why the value of a integer variable is changing after reading a string with scanf?

Tags: c, memory, scanf

Ley us consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char again = 'Y';
    int code;

    do{
        printf("Please inform your option:\n1 - New record\n2 - Delete record\n3 - ecovery record\n4 - Search records\n");
        scanf("%d", &code);

        switch(code){

            case 1:
                printf("Option %d\n",code);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Option %d\n",code);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Option %d\n",code);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Opcao %d\n",code);
                break;
            default:
                printf("code invalido!");
        }

        do{
            printf("Do you wnat to again? [Y - Yes / N - No]: ");
            scanf("%s", &again);
            again = toupper(again);
        }while(again != 'Y' && again != 'N');
        printf("(DEBUG)Option after reading the string %d\n",code);
    }while(again == 'S');

    return 0;
}
```

I know that there is an error in the code, because I'm using scanf with "%s" for reading the information of a single char. It would be better to use "%c".

However, what is interesting for me in this code is that after executing "scanf("%s", &again);", the value of the variable "code" changes to zero. And I'm not sure why this is happening.

Main main hypothesis is that since I'm reading a string with "%s", in this process the scanf is storing the information of two characteres in memory: the character provided by the user and the '\0'. And I think that the information of '\0' is being stored in the memory area assigned to the variable "code".

Does this make sense?

Best regards.

Comment: It's not the null terminators.  It's the newlines.  Where are you discarding whitespace?  You should check the value returned by scanf.

Comment: You're correct, the null terminator is being stored into `code`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `%s` doesn't store the newline in the variable.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Whitespace is automatically discarded by both `%d` and `%s`.

Comment: Furthermore, `scanf` would return 1 here, which is as expected

Comment: Basically, you're causing undefined behavior by storing into a variable that isn't big enough. If you enter N characters in response to `%s`, you need to store into an array of at least N+1 characters.

Comment: Please provide the relative address of the two variables. Is it that the address of `code` is slightly higher than the address of `again`? Please provide e.g. as "Address of `code` is address of `again`+1." or appropriatly similar. Note that even with a [mre], that might be different in your environment than in mine, that is why I ask.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &again);` is incorrect when you have `char again`, which is not the array which `%s `requires, and therefore you have *undefined behaviour* which in this case corrupts another variable. Please try `scanf(" %c", &again);` and note the added space too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that makes sense. But intuition is one thing -- let's check!

Compile with lots of debug info:

```
tmp$ gcc -ggdb test.c
```

Start gdb, run the program:

```
tmp$ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Please inform your option:
1 - New record
2 - Delete record
3 - ecovery record
4 - Search records
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7b04260 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
```

Okay, so I pressed Ctrl-C to interrupt the program. Let's add a watchpoint on `code`.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b04260 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00007ffff7a875e8 in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x7ffff7dd18e0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at fileops.c:592
#2  0x00007ffff7a8860e in __GI__IO_default_uflow (fp=0x7ffff7dd18e0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at genops.c:413
#3  0x00007ffff7a69260 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, 
    argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdbe8, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:634
#4  0x00007ffff7a785df in __isoc99_scanf (format=<optimized out>) at isoc99_scanf.c:37
#5  0x00000000004006c1 in main () at test.c:12
(gdb) frame 5
#5  0x00000000004006c1 in main () at test.c:12
12          scanf("%d", &code);
(gdb) watch code
Hardware watchpoint 1: code
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

Now, when we provide "2" as the input, we can see the value changing:

```
2

Hardware watchpoint 1: code

Old value = 32767
New value = 2
0x00007ffff7a6cde7 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, 
    argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdbe8, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1902
1902    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Okay, that was the first `scanf`. Let's continue to the second one, and give "n" as an answer.

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Option 2
Do you wnat to again? [Y - Yes / N - No]: n

Hardware watchpoint 1: code

Old value = 2
New value = 0
_IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdbe8, 
    errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1194
1194    in vfscanf.c
(gdb) bt
#0  _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdbe8, 
    errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1194
#1  0x00007ffff7a785df in __isoc99_scanf (format=<optimized out>) at isoc99_scanf.c:37
#2  0x000000000040076d in main () at test.c:34
```

Yup, it sure overwrites `code` in there!

What kind of value are we writing?

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function _IO_vfscanf_internal:
[...]
   0x00007ffff7a6a74e <+7886>:  lea    0x1(%rax),%rbx
   0x00007ffff7a6a752 <+7890>:  movb   $0x0,(%rax)
=> 0x00007ffff7a6a755 <+7893>:  je     0x7ffff7a6a77f <_IO_vfscanf_internal+7935>
   0x00007ffff7a6a757 <+7895>:  mov    -0x620(%rbp),%r12
   0x00007ffff7a6a75e <+7902>:  mov    %rbx,%rsi
   0x00007ffff7a6a761 <+7905>:  mov    (%r12),%rdi
[...]
```

`movb` means we're writing a byte. And it's an immediate value (i.e. constant) of zero. It sure looks, walks and quacks like a string terminator!

If we want to be *really* sure, we could try to find the exact source file for this library function.

```
(gdb) disass /s $pc-3,+10
Dump of assembler code from 0x7ffff7a6a752 to 0x7ffff7a6a75c:
vfscanf.c:
1192    in vfscanf.c
   0x00007ffff7a6a752 <_IO_vfscanf_internal+7890>:  movb   $0x0,(%rax)

1193    in vfscanf.c
1194    in vfscanf.c
=> 0x00007ffff7a6a755 <_IO_vfscanf_internal+7893>:  je     0x7ffff7a6a77f <_IO_vfscanf_internal+7935>
   0x00007ffff7a6a757 <_IO_vfscanf_internal+7895>:  mov    -0x620(%rbp),%r12
End of assembler dump.
```

In my case, it's easy: I can install the "glibc-source" package from Ubuntu's apt repository. You may have a harder time, depending on your type of system.

Anyway, check out line 1192. That's definitely a null terminator.

```
glibc-2.23$ find . -name vfscanf.c
./stdio-common/vfscanf.c
glibc-2.23$ less -N ./stdio-common/vfscanf.c
[...]
   1189 
   1190                   str = __mempcpy (str, buf, n);
   1191 #endif
   1192                   *str++ = '\0';
   1193 
   1194                   if ((flags & MALLOC) && str - *strptr != strsize)
   1195                     {
   1196                       char *cp = (char *) realloc (*strptr, str - *strptr);
```